# Passing reference of bean into another bean

Tags: spring

I have a class A which contain the following

```
class A
{

private HashSet<Long> at = new HashSet<Long>();

and it has a constructor like this

A()
{
//set is being initialsised here 

                this.at.add(new Long(44));
        this.at.add(new Long(34));
        this.at.add(new Long(54));
        this.at.add(new Long(55));


}
```

Now following is the spring xml bean defined for it ...

```
<bean id="aa" class="com.abc.A">
        <property name="readPermissionGroup">
      <set>
         <value>03</value>
         <value>13</value>
         <value>54</value>
         <value>55</value>
      </set>
   </property>
    </bean>
```

Now please advise how can I add the above bean aa into bb as the bean bb contain the complete defination of class A

Answer (score 1):

Define class B into Spring context

```
<bean id="bb" class="com.abc.B"></bean>
```

Add an A class referance to class B like

```
class B
{
    private A beanA;

    //setters getters
}
```

and inject bean A to bean B in your xml configuration. Modify bean B defination

```
<bean id="bb" class="com.abc.B">
<property name="beanA" ref="aa" />
</bean>
```

My suggestion is not to use xml to define and inject beans. It is really old, use annotations instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Anotation to inject the bean A. Use @Bean annotation in the class A. @Bean annotation will create bean A.

```
class B {
    @Autowired
    private A beanA;
    // setter and getter
}
```

Here is your class A

```
@Bean
 class A
  {
  private HashSet<Long> at = new HashSet<Long>();
  A()
   {
   //set is being initialsised here 

    this.at.add(new Long(44));
    this.at.add(new Long(34));
    this.at.add(new Long(54));
    this.at.add(new Long(55));
}
```

Comment: OP is using XML configuration.